# How to plot values of x axis with corresponding y values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a graph in MATLAB by using two `for` loops, as show below:

```
for x=0:0.012566370614359173:4*pi
   for n=0:1000
       f(n+1)= (4./pi).*(((-1).^n)./(2*n+1))*cos((2*n+1)*x);
   end
   plot(x,f,'*')
end
```

The problem that it just plots for one x value and it takes long time to execute it in MATLAB ... Even if I put the `plot(x,f,'*')` outside the `for` loops it takes a very long time to run...

How can I plot the f values for all x values ? Is there another way instead of using two `for` loops ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any for loops at all. Also, you used some matrix-wise operators (`*`) where I don't believe you intended them - as opposed to element-wise operators (`.*`) -  note the changes I made to your definition of `f`

```
x = 0:0.012566370614359173:4*pi;

n = 1:1001;

f = (4./pi).*(((-1).^n)./(2*n+1)).*cos((2.*n+1).*x);

plot(x,f,'*');
```

[image]

Comment: thank you ... does your f function calculating the sum from 0 to infinity ? I need the f function to be a sum and then plot its values to see convergence and divergence ... peace

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but the function is plotted from 0 < x <= 4pi, as per your original code. It appears to converge to 0 as x goes to infinity...

Comment: yes ,,, can you please see the original f function here : http://www.atomic.physics.lu.se/fileadmin/atomfysik/Education/Mandatory_cources/FAFA01_Fysik_-_Mekanik_och_Vaagor/Inlaemningsuppgifter.pdf           page 2 task 5

Comment: I dont speak whatever language that is, so it's hard for me to understand exactly what I am being asked

Comment: You should use `symsum` to answer your convergence question, though I strongly suspect it converges to 0. If you want to try that, type `help symsum` in the MATLAB command window, or google some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the loop for the x.

```
x=0:0.012566370614359173:4*pi;
f = zeros(1,numel(x));

for n = 0:numel(x)-1
    f(n+1) = (4/pi)*(((-1)^n)./(2*n+1))*cos((2*n+1)*x(n+1));
end

plot(x,f,'*');
```

Comment: now it works .. your plot is not exactly like the plot of @Elijah Rockers .. Which one do you think is more accurate ... thank you

Comment: Both are same. Just change n = 1:1001 to n = 0:1000 and you will get the same plot. Also, his way is better.